# Scala: group by equivalence relation

Tags: scala, grouping, equivalence-classes

I have a `List[String]`. I want to group it by a given equivalence relation:

```
def f(x: String, y: String): Boolean = {
  if (x == "" || y == "") {
    false
  } else {
    x == y
  }
}
```

I have tried method `groupBy`, but I cannot achieve empty strings to be in separate groups.

I would prefer the answer for any equivalence relation `f(x: String, y: String): Boolean`, not just this one.

EDIT: I have not specified, but the input type is really `List[String]`, not `List[(String, String)]`, `f` is a `binary relation`, that's why it has 2 String inputs, and expected return type is `List[List[String]]`

EDIT: As @andrey-tyukin mentioned, `f` is not an equivalence relation, so requesting "answer for any equivalence relation" is nonsense.

EDIT: An example:

```
Input: List("a", "a", "b", "", "")
Output: List(List("a", "a"), List("b"), List(""), List(""))
```

- "a" == "a", that's why they go in the same group
- Although "" == "", but `f` would result in false, so they are not in the same group

Comment: Why `f` takes two parameters? Do you have a `List[(String, String)]`? BTW I think `partition` can help you in this task...

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you give an example input and the result groups?

Comment: That's not an equivalence relation, because it's not reflexive: `f("", "")` is false.

Comment: So input `List("a","a","b","a")` would result with 3 groups: `("a","a")`, `("b")`, and `("a")`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
val strs = List("a", "", "b", "c", "", "a", "a", "c")
val grps = strs.sorted.foldLeft(Nil: List[List[String]]){ 
  case (h::tl, s) if h.head == s && s.nonEmpty => (s::h) :: tl 
  case (r, s) => List(s) :: r 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupBy` partitioning by value, not by relation.

You need a function that will map your any equivalent object to same value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, it seems like your data is `List[(String, String)]`?

If so, you can try this

```scala
def f(x: String, y: String): Boolean = {
  if (x == "" || y == "") {
    false
  } else {
    x == y
  }
}

val xs = List(("", ""), ("", "1"), ("1", "1"), ("1", "2"))

val res = xs.groupBy((f _).tupled)
println(res)
// Map(false -> List((,), (,1), (1,2)), true -> List((1,1)))
```